# TypeScript mutating prop

Tags: typescript

Why is `born_date` being mutated? I'm cloning it to `date` before making changes to it, is there something I'm missing?

```
export default class Gigasecond {
  born_date: Date;

  constructor(date: Date) {
    this.born_date = date;
  }

  date(): Date {
    let date = this.born_date;
    let date_plus_giga = date.getSeconds() + 1000000000;
    date.setSeconds(date_plus_giga);
    return date;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let date = this.born_date;` is not achieving your desired behavior of cloning the date. It’s copying a reference to the date object, and then the call to setSeconds later mutates the object (which is both referenced by the member `born_date` and the local variable `date`).

To clone the date object, you can do this: `let date = new Date(this.born_date.valueOf());`.